# Get profile picture from Facebook Graph-API

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-3.1

this method to retrieve the photo facebook profile does not work anymore

```
ImageView user_picture;
 userpicture=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.userpicture);
 URL img_value = null;
 img_value = new URL("http://graph.facebook.com/"+id+"/picture?type=large");
 Bitmap mIcon1 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(img_value.openConnection().getInputStream());
userpicture.setImageBitmap(mIcon1);
```

mIcon1 is null

it functioned normally but not now and I think that facebook has changed something 
when I check the URL that redirects to another url

http: //graph.facebook.com/"id example(2154847)"/picture?type=large ---> https:// fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-prn2/t1.0-  1/s200x200/1480603_10201506903424508_71775 13962104534241_n.jpg

**Edit** 
solution :

```
 public Bitmap getPhotoFacebook(final String id) {

    Bitmap bitmap=null;
    final String nomimg = "https://graph.facebook.com/"+id+"/picture?type=large";
    URL imageURL = null;

    try {
        imageURL = new URL(nomimg);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) imageURL.openConnection();
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects( true );
        connection.connect();
        InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
        //img_value.openConnection().setInstanceFollowRedirects(true).getInputStream()
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);

    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return bitmap;

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
img_value.openConnection().setInstanceFollowRedirects(true).getInputStream()
```

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
public static Bitmap getFacebookProfilePicture(String userID){
    URL imageURL = new URL("https://graph.facebook.com/" + userID + "/picture?type=large");
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageUrl.openConnection().getInputStream());

    return bitmap;
}

Bitmap bitmap = getFacebookProfilePicture(userId);
```

Make sure you are using **https** instead of **http**.